# Impala mathematical operation containing avg fails with AnalysisException

Tags: hive, impala

I am attempting to subtract a value in a column (`column_18`) from the average of another column (`avg(column_19)`) and obtain this result as a third column (`result`) for **each row** of the table:

```
cur.execute("Select avg(column_19) - column_18 as result FROM test1")
```

This doesn't seem to be working well, and I get this error:

```
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): SUM(column_19) / COUNT(column_19) - column_18
```

I do not want the result to be grouped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`avg()` in this context is an [aggregate function](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_aggregate_functions.html), which means that it is applied to a group of rows, which may specified with a `GROUP BY` clause (or all rows if not specified). The output of an aggregate expression is a single value per-group, so it is not applied per-row as you want.

However, you can accomplish what you're trying to do in a few ways. I think the easiest is by using avg() as an [analytic function](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html). For example, you can do something like:

```
select column_19, column_18, (avg(column_19) over () - column_18) as result from test1
```

See the documentation for more details about how aggregations and analytic functions work.